# How to set SparseMatrix.valuePtr(), SparseMatrix.outerIndexPtr() and SparseMatrix.innerIndexPtr() for CSR Format?

Tags: c++, eigen

I already have my sparse matrix data in [CSR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), ie: I already have data for non zero values ( in the form of `double[]`), the row and the column index ( both in the form of `int[]`) of the non zero values.

My problem is, how can I assign them directly to Sparse Matrix in eigen library? I know that the relevant fields in Sparse Matrix are `valuePtr`, `outerIndexPtr` and `innerIndexPtr`, but I can't set the pointer directly as per below:

```
//the relevant SpMat fields (valuePtr,outerIndexPtr,innerIndexPtr) are not able to set

static SpMat CSRFormat2(double* nonZeroPtr, int* rowIndex, 
int* colIndex, int totDOF,  int nonZeroCount)  
{
    SpMat sparseMatrix = SpMat(totDOF,totDOF);

    double *nonZ=sparseMatrix.valuePtr();
    nonZ=nonZeroPtr;

    int *outerIndex = sparseMatrix.outerIndexPtr();
    outerIndex=rowIndex;

    int *innerIndex = sparseMatrix.innerIndexPtr();
    innerIndex = colIndex;

    sparseMatrix.reserve(nonZeroCount);

    return sparseMatrix;

}
```

I don't want to iterate over the non zero values and set everything again. That would be inefficient, I think.

How to set `SparseMatrix.valuePtr()`, `SparseMatrix.outerIndexPtr()` and `SparseMatrix.innerIndexPtr()`, if this is possible at all?

Comment: You are looking for [Map<SparseMatrix<double> >](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Map_3_01SparseMatrixType_01_4.html)

Comment: @ggael, would you like to expand your comment into a proper answer? So that it can be voted (up)

Comment: this doesn't look like csr. you would need to use a different pointer in eigen for csr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [the comment from ggael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481785/how-to-set-sparsematrix-valueptr-sparsematrix-outerindexptr-and-sparsematri#comment72127756_42481785), this is how I solve the problem:

```
      ///CSR format: nonZeroArray, rowIndex, colIndex
      SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> ConstructSparseMatrix(int rowCount, int colCount, int nonZeroCount, double *nonZeroArray, int *rowIndex, int *colIndex)
        {
            Map<SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor>> spMap(rowCount, colCount, nonZeroCount,  rowIndex, colIndex, nonZeroArray, 0);
            SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> matrix= spMap.eval();
            matrix.reserve(nonZeroCount);
            return matrix;
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need "matrix.reserve(nonZeroCount);"?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack that I haven't really tested (recently). It does copy the values, however:

```
SparseMatrix<double, whatever, indexType> m;
m.resize(rows, cols);
m.makeCompressed();
m.resizeNonZeros(nnz);

memcpy((void*)(m.valuePtr()), (void*)(valueSrc), sizeof(double) * nnz);
memcpy((void*)(m.outerIndexPtr()), (void*)(outerIndexPtrSrc), sizeof(indexType) * outSz);
memcpy((void*)(m.innerIndexPtr()), (void*)(innerIndexPtrSrc), sizeof(indexType) * nnz);

m.finalize();
```

If you would rather not copy the memory, then just assigning the pointers (`sparseMatrix.valuePtr() = nonZeroPtr;`) will cause problems later, as the matrix thinks it owns the memory and will delete it on destruction. You should probably use `std::swap` instead.

One last note, the index type of the `Eigen::SparseMatrix` may not be `int`, so you may want to deal with that before just copying/swapping.