# how to convert UMFpack sparse matrix to Eigen sparse matrix?

Tags: visual-studio, sparse-matrix, eigen, suitesparse, umfpack

I have a code that was written to use UMFpack sparse matrix solver but need to convert it to Eigen sparse matrix but I am running into memory problems.

I have Ai (row pointers), Ap (column pointers) and Ax (array). Trying to solve Ax=b. How can I pass these pointers and Ax or change them for Eigen?

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map_3_01SparseMatrixType_01_4.html

Comment: @chtz I am using row-major ordering. The umfpack uses the cumulative sum of nonzero entries over the row, Ap[i+1] . However, eigen uses a const pointer to the array of the starting positions of the inner and outer vectors. Is there a way to switch between the two.

Comment: @chtz I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42568885/8447424  . I currently have the sparse array as a column so the I guess the outerIndexPtr would be the same thing as Ap in UMFpack? Is that correct?