# In Eigen is it possible to construct an Eigen::sparseMatrix from its Column major representation?

Tags: eigen

I have the 3 vectors that make the Column major representation of a matrix, i.e.

- `i` indicating the row of each non zero entry
- `p` given the starting index of each column
- `x` the values of the non zero entries

Eigen advises to construct the `sparseMatrix` with the triple representation, which would be straightforward to do but it's an unnecessary step.
So how can I initialize the `sparseMatrix` from `i`, `p` and `x`?

Comment: Have a look at `Map<SparseMatrix<...> >` [at bottom of this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html) -- you don't even need to copy your data.

Comment: Actually there's already a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481785/how-to-set-sparsematrix-valueptr-sparsematrix-outerindexptr-and-sparsematri